# Application stops when hiding ActionBar

Tags: android

I've created a brand new Android project with blank activity with "Hello World" TextView on it. When I hide ActionBar and then run on AVD the application stops. The error looks likes this: "Unfortunately,  has stopped"

I've tried this methods of hiding action bar, and nothing worked on me:

1) `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"....>`

2) in `onCreate()` method getActionBar().hide();

Here is the red strings in logcat:

```
02-13 18:42:43.373    2123-2123/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-13 18:42:43.383      794-948/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property

02-13 18:42:43.523    2123-2123/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{styleru.it_lab.reaschedule/styleru.it_lab.reaschedule.loginActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at styleru.it_lab.reaschedule.loginActivity.onCreate(loginActivity.java:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

02-13 18:42:43.733      794-947/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: @Lal here is the red strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

to this:

`public class MainActivity extends Activity`

Answer (score 0):

you could use requestWindowFeature before setcontentview

```
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. 
`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: use it before setContentView(R.layout.)

Comment: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  setContentView(R.layout.act_temp);